# How can I assign a media file to the storefront presentation via API in Shopware 6?

Tags: shopware6-api

How to assign a Media File istead of a word to the selection section of the Storefront Presentation via api in Shopware 6 ?
I'm trying to get media file displayed instead of a text in the selection section. The image shows how it's supposed to look on the right side (image of backpack).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojcNe.png)

If a product is available in multiple colors then you have a selection section on the product page where you can choose which color of the product should be displayed on the product page. That is shown in the screenshot that i posted. In the screenshot you can see the selection section where you can see that the testproduct is available in two colors. One color you can choose the backpack in is cyan, which is shown as a word. The green backpack is shown as a picture where you can see the green backpack. I need to know what i have to ad to my json product post so that in slection section of the product page a picture of the product is displayed instead of a word.

My searchin brought me to the conclusion that it has to be set in "configuratorGroupConfig". I tried setting the "representation": to "image" instead of "text".

```
   "configuratorSettings":[
                {
                    "id": 'Mediafolder-UUID',
                    "representation": "image",
                    "expressionForListings": true
                }
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thx

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To assign a media file to the storefront presentation via the API in Shopware 6, you can follow these steps:

1. First, make sure you have the necessary authentication credentials and permissions to access the Shopware 6 API.
2. Use the API endpoint `/api/v2/_action/media/{mediaId}/media-folder/{folderId}` to assign the media file to the storefront presentation. Replace `{mediaId}` with the ID of the media file you want to assign and `{folderId}` with the ID of the desired media folder for the presentation.
3. Make a POST request to the API endpoint with the appropriate headers and authentication credentials. Ensure that you include the correct `mediaId` and `folderId` in the URL.

   Here's an example using JavaScript and the `fetch` function:

```js
const mediaId = 'your_media_id';
const folderId = 'your_folder_id';

fetch(`/api/v2/_action/media/${mediaId}/media-folder/${folderId}`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer your_api_token',
  },
})
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      // Media file successfully assigned to the storefront presentation
      console.log('Media file assigned successfully');
    } else {
      // Handle error response
      console.error('Failed to assign media file:', response.status);
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle network or other errors
    console.error('Error assigning media file:', error);
  });
```

Make sure to replace `'your_media_id'`, `'your_folder_id'`, and `'your_api_token'` with the actual values specific to your Shopware 6 installation.

By using this API endpoint, you can assign a media file to the desired media folder for the storefront presentation in Shopware 6 programmatically.

Comment: thank you very much for your attempt to help.
I'm not looking for a way to ad media file to a certain media-folder. I think this is what your example is showin. The media file is already in the right Media-Folder.